# Make a long webpage split over multiple PDF pages via “pagesplit:true” option using jsPDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

I have searched high and low for weeks to an answer to this but can't seem to find one that works.

Here is the code I have:

```
function pdf() {
     html2canvas(document.body, {
         onrendered: function(canvas) {
           var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')

           var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
           var options = {
               pagesplit: true
            };
           doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',0,0,<?php echo "$width";?>,0);
           doc.save('webpage-pdf.pdf');
           }
      });
}
```

The code will create a PDF but it will only make 1 single PDF page.
If the webpage is long enough it should be split over multiple PDF pages.

This is where the pagesplit: true option comes in. But no matter how I try it the pagesplit option does nothing and it's still only produces 1 page with the rest of the website missing/cutoff from the PDF file.

Does anyone know how to turn this option on, am I using the API correctly?

Thanks, Paul.

Comment: :So how did you solve your problem??...I am stuck up with the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `PageSplit` as used in the below code

```
<script>
 function demoFromHTML() {

     var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4')

     pdf.addHTML(document.body,margins.left,margins.top,{pagesplit:true},function() {
            pdf.save('CDC.pdf');
        });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems **addHTML** has been **deprecated**
[addHTML deprecated](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/global.html#addHTML)
instead use [pdfjs html](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/module-html.html#%7Ehtml)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
onClickPDF() {
   const printElement = document.getElementById('print');
   const pdf = new jspdf('portrait', 'mm', 'a4');
   const docWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
   pdf.html(printElement, {
      autoPaging: 'text',
      margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
      width: docWidth,
      windowWidth: 1000}).then(
         () => {
            pdf.save(`payment_plan_${this.planData.plan_title.replace(' ', '_')}.pdf`);
         });
}
```

this is working fine with me